# analysis square waves oscillator: how do I calculate the values?

Tags: oscillator, analysis

Which are the Vc (V+) and V-, I's and Vout values in these circuits? The node i's and the Vc and Ic?

[image: square wave oscillators]

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you mean the supply voltage for the Op-Amps.

In the Motorola one it doesn't tell you what the supply voltages are. Just that your Vcc or Input Voltage has to be more than 4V and the Vo is the output. In the Texas Instruments one it tells you that the supply voltage is one sided so +15V and gnd and the output is the Salida.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. But I men that I need to make the manual analysis of these circuits. I mean: to calculate with the R variables and C values which are the V+, V-, Vc and I's in the R's and the nodes. As a classical analysis. In pspice I simulated the first one and OK. Not the same for the second. Now: i'm trying to get the classic analysis. Im doing: in T=0, the Vc=0. With IC>0 until the C is charged...etc. If V->V+ --> V0=Vcc. And the node ecuations?: (vcc-v+)/330K=(V+-V0)/330k + (v+-0)/330K ?....I do not know exactly how to end this "mathecal" analys.

Comment: Ahh okay I thought that might be the case, maybe edit the question to say 'how do I calculate the values' or 'how to rearrange equations to get'. Sorry I don't think I would be much help. All I can suggest is calling V+ something else so you don't get so confused with V+-. This is a personal point though so if it works for you there is no harm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I 'm editting the question. Good advice